# Setting default fonts in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa

How can I set the default font of an NSTextView component? I need to have an area in my app where users can make changes to a plain text file, and I'd like for the font to be a monospaced font.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849212/814730) was close, but wouldn't do it - had to access the textStorage object of the NSTextView first:

```
[[myNSTextView textStorage] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:11]];
```

Comment: From the NSText (superclass of NSTextView) documentation: “Sets the font of all the receiver’s text to <var>aFont</var>.” If that didn't work for you, you should look into why.

Comment: Furthermore, you should use the user's preferred fixed-pitch font and size, not a hard-coded font and size. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFont/userFixedPitchFontOfSize:

Comment: Also with this answer, my text storage seemed to stop allowing unicode characters. Such as '안녕하세요!'. Instead my NSTextView displays '!'.

Comment: Don't know why, but this didn't work for me, even though `[myNSTextView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:11]]` did.

Comment: I also had to remove 'textStorage' to get it to work

Comment: One thing I've noticed — if your `NSTextView` is rendering an `NSAttributedString`, setting `font` on the text view itself doesn't seem to do anything. You'll have to set the font via attributes on the `NSAttributedString` instead.

Answer (score 17):

```
NSFont* font = <whatever>;
[textView setFont: font];
```